# lexical error at character '\DEL' when doing runhaskell

Tags: haskell, ghc, runhaskell

Heres my code:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = product [1..n]

main = print(factorial 50)
```

I don't get any errors compiling, but when i run the compiled code

```
runhaskell test
```

I get this error:

```
test:1:1: lexical error at character '\DEL'
```

What is causing this? How do I solve the problem?

**UPDATES**

I did a hexdump of the file:

```
$ hexdump -x test.hs
```

and got

```
0000000    6166    7463    726f    6169    206c    3a3a    4920    746e
0000010    6765    7265    2d20    203e    6e49    6574    6567    0a72
0000020    6166    7463    726f    6169    206c    206e    203d    7270
0000030    646f    6375    2074    315b    2e2e    5d6e    6d0a    6961
0000040    206e    203d    7270    6e69    2874    6166    7463    726f
0000050    6169    206c    3035    0029                                
0000057
```

Comment: Hex dump your file to see if it has a `0x7f` in it.

Comment: Nope, no `0x7f`. please see edit

Comment: I added a 0x7f to a file with the same source code you showed, and got the exact same error message.  Without the 0x7f, it worked.

Comment: I can't tell the difference between Haskell and a bar of soap but all the examples I can find have `runhaskell test.hs` (with the extension). Are you sure you're not picking up a binary file called just `test` somewhere?

Comment: @paxdiablo- I think you have it, I just ran `runHaskell` on the compiled binary, and got the same error message.  @dopatraman- runHaskell is an interpreter, it takes source code, if you have a compiled binary you can run it directly.

Comment: Adjusted your code, by the way. That hex dump shows there's no `-- test.hs` line at the top.

Comment: wait, that is what i did. I ran `ghc test.hs` and that linked a `test` binary file. Then I did `runhaskell test` (the binary, not the `.hs` file). Is that what my mistake was?

Comment: maybe this is a dumb question, but where do i use the binary generated by the compiler?

Comment: @paxdiablo - I don't know if you can boast about not knowing Haskell anymore; not now that you've got a positive score in [haskell]. Next thing you know, another tag badge...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that you're using `runhaskell` with the *source* file `test.hs` rather than the compiled binary `test`.

If you've used something like `ghc` to create an executable file, you can just run that directly, with something like:

```
./test
```

Be aware that `test` is probably not a good name for an executable since it's a built-in command on some shells, something that's burnt me before when my `test` executable doesn't seem to do what I wanted :-)

Comment: When I try running the executable directly a blank line gets printed to the console.

Comment: this happened to me. Usually I only have `foo.hs` in my directory, and `runghc foo` works fine. However, I found that when I do a *mixture* of `runghc` and `ghc`, the former attempts to run the compiled binary `foo` as a source file